# Java: Why doesn't the following construction throw ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java

I have the following structure:

```
public class Object1{

    private HashMap<Double, Node> myMap;
    ...

    public void cancelItem(Item o) {
            for(Map.Entry<Double, Node> nn: myMap.entrySet()) {
                if(nn.getValue().containItem(o)) {
                    nn.getValue().cancelItemFromNode(o);
                }
            }
     }
}
```

and another class

```
public class Node{
    private HashMap<String,Item> itemIDHashMap; 

    public boolean containItemID(Item o) {
            return itemIDHashMap.containsKey(o.getItemID());
    }

    public void cancelItemFromNode(Item o) {
        if(itemIDHashMap.containsKey(o.getItemID())) {
            itemIDHashMap.remove(o.getItemID());
        } 
    }
}
```

So the code above does this: whenever `Object1`'s `cancelItem` method is invoked, it iterates the `myMap` hashmap to find a `Node` , which contains another hashmap `itemIDHashMap` , and check whether the `itemIDHashMap` contains the same item ID, if it does, then remove the item from `itemIDHashMap`.

Now, from my understanding since I am iterating over the hashmap `myMap` without using iterator and I am trying to remove elements from the hashmap, why does it not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` at runtime?

**UPDATE:**
Apologies. I forgot to clarify. I understand I am in fact iterating over one hashmap but removing key value pair from another hashmap. However, in my design above, I believe I am still modifying the content of `Node` , which is still part of the `myMap` hashmap because I am removing `Item` key value pair from the hashmap of `Node` class. 
So technically , I am still modifying the contents of the `myMap` hashmap ?

Comment: You are not modifying the Map you are iterating over.

Comment: regarding your update: **No**, modifying your `Node` doesn't affect the `Map`. Your `Map` doesn't even know that a `Node` contains another `Map`, so why should it care if you change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are iterating over the entry set of one `Map` - `myMap` - but remove entries from different `Map`s - `itemIDHashMap`. Therefore there's no reason for `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown.

Removing entries from the `itemIDHashMap` instance variable of a `Node`, which is a value of the `Map` you are iterating over, makes **no structural changes** in that `Map`, and is therefore allowed.

Here are some relevant quotes from the `HashMap` Javadoc, which explain when `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown while iterating over the entries of the `Map`:

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.
>
> ...
>
> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: **if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException**. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

`entrySet()` is one of the mentioned "collection view methods".

Comment: but to a certain extent, I am still editing the content of `Node` , which is still part of the `myMap` hashmap because I am removing `Item` key value pair from the `Node`. So technically , am I not modifying the contents of the `myMap` hashmap ?

Comment: @user1769197 the `ConcurrentModificationException` arises when you iterate over a `Collection` and modify that **same** `Collection`. It isn't about the `Node`s, they don't care about which `Map` they are in at what time

Comment: @user1769197 mutating a value (or key) of a Map doesn't cause a structural change to that Map, and therefore can be done safely while iterating over that Map.

Comment: @user1769197 In more detail: the problem arises when you create an `Iterator` object, which sole purpose it is to iterate over a `Collection`. Is is created, it looks at the `Collection` and wants to go through it while returning each element exactly once. If the `Collection` changes while it is doing so, it will get "confused". And when you use a for-each loop, you are implicitly creating an `Iterator`

Comment: oh i see. So as best practise, should I edit my code to use iterator i.e. `while(iteratorr.hasNext())....` instead of `for each loop` that I am using ?

Comment: @user1769197 no, using enhanced for loop (for each loop) is perfectly fine in your example, since you are making no structural changes.

Comment: @user1769197 stay with your loop, it is fine. But it is good to know that your loop will be converted into a `while(iterator.hasNext())` loop internally, since this is - loosely speaking - the source of the `ConcurrentModificationException`